# Comodo PositiveSSL + Windows 2008R2 / IIS7.5: error on Android only

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ssl-certificate, iis-7.5

I have an SSL certificate, which is correctly working with all major *desktop* browsers (IE, Chrome, FF), and on Windows Phone and iOS, but on Android.

I guess I've installed my certificate in the right order, because it shows the certificate hierarchy as followed on the server:

(root) AddTrust External CA \ (intermediate) Comodo RSA Certification Authority \ Comodo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA \ myunluckydomainnameexample.com

I know, that only AddTrust is in the list of Android's root CAs, so it should be a problem with the intermediate ones. How can I investigate it further on my Windows 2008 R2?

I found the openssl tool:

```
        $ openssl s_client -connect myunluckydomainnameexample.com:443

CONNECTED(00000003)
    depth=1 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
    verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
    verify return:0
    ---
    Certificate chain
     0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL/CN=skaelede.hu
       i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
     1 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
       i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
    ---
    Server certificate
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

I've compared it's output with a known working site, `https://ssllabs.com` and it gives the following output:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect ssllabs.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Certification Authority verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL/CN=www.ssllabs.com
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
 1 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
 2 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

..which certificate am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems too much modification in the Certificate Store leads to a limbo state of the certificate-chain, which is not curable by restarting IIS. After a scheduled reboot on the server, all changes in the CA-chain became effective and since then it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The order needs to be 1) server CRT 2) Domain/EV/WildC CRT 3) 2nd CA

I just battled this problem (nogo on Chrome Android), here is how I fixed it with a domain certificate.

unzip the zip file I got in my email

```
unzip www_mysite_com.zip
```

Create a certificate bundle with all the CA's but skipping the root `COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt`

```
cat www_mysite_com.crt COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt > www.mysite.com.bundle.crt
```

I'm using nginx so my crt line looks like:

```
ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/www.mysite.com.bundle.crt;
```

Works great and I finally got chrome on Android to work.

Regards